# Magento 2 - Server side vs client side compilation (Pros and Cons)?

Tags: magento2, admin, compilation

What do I need to know to compare Server side and client side compilation mode on my Magento 2 store?
This config is on **Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Frontend Development Workflow**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Server-Side compilation

Server-side compilation is the **default choice**, used for first time compilation after setup and for production mode.

**Cons:**

- Slow
- Global recompile
- Need to delete static files before each run

**Pros:**

- No additional setup required
- Works on server side

### Client-Side compilation

Client-side compilation with Javascript is **optional** and is used to quickly preview changes and to debug small issues.

**Cons:**

- Annoying blinking before styles compile
- Global recompile

**Pros:**

- No need for additional setup, can be switched in Admin area
- Fast

Comment: From version 2.2.1-dev on virtual machine in developer mode - client-side breaks everything, $template becomes undefined in Renderer